# Floating Point Values in Java 1.7.0_97

Tags: java, floating-point, java-7, precision, ieee-754

I have following test code snippet, which has a float type variable `f`, and I have assigned the value `3627.299685` to it.
After that, I am creating one more variable `d2` of type double, by typecasting `f` to double.

Printing the values of both `f` and `d2`, my observation results are bit weird, as both the variable values do not match exactly the value assigned to the variable.

Is it limitation of the Java 1.7.0_97, 64Bit server?
Or is there any other way, we can print the exact value of the variable here?

```
public class TestFloat  {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      float f = 3627.299685f;
      double d2 = (double)f;
      System.out.println("Float:" + f);
      System.out.println("Float converted to Double:" + d2);
   }
}

user@test01:/tmp$ java TestFloat
Float:3627.2998
Float converted to Double:3627.2998046875
```

Comment: it is not possible to have exact representation for every possible float and double

Comment: "as both the variable values, doest not matches exactly with the value assigned to the variable" - well that isn't much of a surprise, given that you've assigned a value with 10 significant decimal digits to a value of a type that only has 8-9 digits of precision...

Comment: The value printed for `d2` is actually the precise value of both the `float` and the `double`.

Comment: The double and float are equal to each other. The printed float value is rounded to less precision because it is a less precise data type.